# Upgrading Debian 9 to Debian 10 on BeagleBone AI

Tags: debian, beagleboard

Can someone point me to the correct articles/docs on how I will be able to upgrade Debian 9 to Debian 10 on BeagleBone AI ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First head to [this page](https://beagleboard.org/latest-images) and download the latest image for your board.

[image]

Then read the [BeagleBone official updating guide](https://beagleboard.org/getting-started#update) to update you board with the latest image.

Comment: This is a destructive update, anything in the Flash gets overwritten. I'm not entirely sure if that's what the person asking this was after.